# Status 200 for 404 Not Found CMS page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cms, 404-page

In short, Magento returns status 200 for the 404 Not Found CMS page, for what seems to be a pretty standard configuration:

[image]

Everything works fine when the URL is changed to `cms/index/defaultNoRoute`, the default Not Found page is loaded with status 404.

Also, absolutely everything works fine on a copy of the website on a different server. Which would lead me to suspect the Apache configuration. Not sure though what to look out for.

Here are response headers for both defaultNoRoute and noRoute actions:

```
$ curl -I http://www.server.com/cms/index/defaultNoRoute
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2013 12:56:07 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie: frontend=332f53c81eee1f730f430c0f59e0dd83; expires=Thu, 25-Apr-2013 13:56:08 GMT; path=/; domain=www.server.com; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Status: 404 File not found
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

$ curl -I http://www.server.com/cms/index/noRoute
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2013 12:56:11 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie: frontend=361b3804feaea66a6fcdf1aee048ce44; expires=Thu, 25-Apr-2013 13:56:12 GMT; path=/; domain=www.server.com; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction? Cheers.

Comment: Are you using Varnish and incorrectly caching 404s

Comment: Varnish is not in use. Also, enabling/disabling Magento cache makes no difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817449/force-magento-no-route-to-return-status-301-instead-of-404 possibly related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience this is most often caused by poorly written CMS integrations. It's not uncommon for a CMS integration to rewrite the noRoute action to catch when Magento would issue a 404, grab content from a CMS (if available) and then serve it up in the content section of the page.

What goes wrong, however, is when these custom integrations then fail to detect when they also do not have content for the URL in the CMS and indiscriminately send out a 200 response code with either blank content or a 404 content page served from the CMS (but with a 200 response code).

In the case of no content, in this type of integration, the trick is to simply forward the request to the default no route action and/or fall through and let the parent controller method handle the 404 response.

Do you have a CMS integration module of some sort installed? If so, I would suggest isolating it to either prove or rule it out as the cause.

Comment: That would make perfect sense, Wordpress and Fishpig Wordpress integration is installed on the website. The problem is, though, everything works fine on the dev copy of the website...

Comment: Are both dev and production servers case-sensitive?

Comment: Nope, the dev server, where it works, is an OS X with case insensitive FS.

Comment: In that case, it's possible (although not entirely likely) that something on the site is "working" on development but not on production thus triggering different behavior. I would suggest both setting up development on a case-sensitive drive to match production (unless production is Windows and insensitive as well) and test there. If that doesn't replicate the behavior, try and find out if there is anything overriding any of the *Action methods on the `Mage_Cms_IndexController` controller class in the core namespace. Or perhaps setting a response code in an observer somewhere after it's called

Comment: The reason I don't suspect Apache configuration is because it is returning a 404 response code in one scenario and not the other, which means it's not blanketly overriding the application response codes. Seeing that both curl requests have Set-cookie headers with a 'frontend' cookie, they are both hitting the Magento application

Comment: Yeah, good thinking. But then you also have two installations with different behavior, which would point to something outside of Magento.

Comment: That is why I brought up the file-system needing to have the same case-sensitivity on *both* instances. Having case-insensitive on dev can easily cause things to work on dev which won't work (and sometimes cause utter failure) on production.

Comment: Another possibility is that some modules are loading in a different order on production. I've seen it happen, and the only way to solve it is by setting the dependencies correctly in the modules where it affects the operation of the code.

Comment: These are some good points! I've just set up the copy on a Centos server and the 404 page behaves as expected (that is, different from production). I'm going to check the module loading order now.

Comment: I haven't been able to narrow down the problem using any of ways suggested here, but I'm sure others will find them useful.